# Best Practice for Exporting an App's Data to XML via PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have a business app and I want to give my users the ability to export their data at anytime.

I'm aware that I can write an XML file semi-manually by doing something like this:
http://www.kirupa.com/web/mysql_xml_php.htm

But, I thought I'd ask if this is the best practice?  Or is there some framework I can use to do this more easily/quickly?  Maybe there isn't - it won't be too hard to do it the above way.

Also, less importantly - XML is the best format to export to, right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just had a friend who suggested that csv might be a better format since regular people can do something with that data.  Definitely something to consider.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend having a look at the PEAR package [XML_Query2XML](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Query2XML).

Answer (score 1):

The best format to export your data largely depends on what kind of data you are exporting.  For some datasets, a simple export to Comma Separated Value (CSV) files will be sufficient.  If your data is more complex, there is a PEAR package that will serialize PHP values into XML objects.

This tutorial will show you how to use the various PEAR packages to take your existing data in PHP and convert it relatively easily to well structured XML:

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/xml-php-pear-xml_serializer

I would definitely recommend XML as an option for exporting your data as there are a vast number of tools and technologies that interact well with XML; XQuery, XSLT, etc.

Comment: This package looks relatively easy to use... I'll be giving it a try.  Thanks for the answer and detailed explanation - appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

there is no reason to reinvent the wheel, [mysql already support selecting result into xml format since 5.1](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/xml-in-mysql5.1-6.0.html)

> XML is the best format to export to, right?

too subjective, some said yes, some said no ...

Answer (score 0):

I would you php's DomDocument class. its really easy to use >> http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php